# With regards to urllib AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'

Tags: python

```
import re
import string
import shutil
import os
import os.path
import time
import datetime
import math
import urllib
from array import array
import random

filehandle = urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com/') #open webpage
s = filehandle.read() #read 
print s #display

#what i plan to do with it once i get the first part working
#results = re.findall('[<td style="font-weight:bold;" nowrap>$][0-9][0-9][0-9][.][0-9][0-9][</td></tr></tfoot></table>]',s)
#earnings = '$ '
#for money in results:
#earnings = earnings + money[1]+money[2]+money[3]+'.'+money[5]+money[6]
#print earnings
#raw_input()
```

this is the code that i have so far. now i have looked at all the other forums that give solutions such as the name of the script, which is parse_Money.py, and i have tried doing it with urllib.request.urlopen AND i have tried running it on python 2.5, 2.6, and 2.7. If anybody has any suggestions it would be really welcome, thanks everyone!!
--Matt

---*EDIT*---
I also tried this code and it worked, so im thinking its some kind of syntax error, so if anybody with a sharp eye can point it out, i would be very appreciative.

```
import shutil
import os
import os.path
import time
import datetime
import math
import urllib
from array import array
import random
b = 3

#find URL
URL = raw_input('Type the URL you would like to read from[Example: http://www.google.com/] :')



while b == 3:
    #get file name
    file1 = raw_input('Enter a file name for the downloaded code:')
    filepath = file1 + '.txt'
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        print 'File already exists'
        b = 3
    else:
        print 'Filename accepted'
        b = 4

file_path = filepath
#open file
FileWrite = open(file_path, 'a')


#acces URL
filehandle = urllib.urlopen(URL)

#display souce code
for lines in filehandle.readlines():
    FileWrite.write(lines)
    print lines
print 'The above has been saved in both a text and html file'

#close files
filehandle.close()
FileWrite.close()
```

Comment: Looks like you *totally* screwed up your Python installation. What's the operating system and what is inside the file with the filename `urllib.__file__`?

Comment: i've tried running your erroneous code on IDLE, and it executed just fine. though i didn't import anything besides `urllib`. probably you might want to try doing that. other than that, i don't think there's anything wrong w/ your code in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

[it appears](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html) that the `urlopen` method is available in the `urllib.request` module and not in the `urllib` module as you're expecting.

rule of thumb - if you're getting an `AttributeError`, that field/operation is not present in the particular module.

**EDIT** - Thanks to AndiDog for pointing out - this is a solution valid for Py 3.x, and not applicable to Py2.x!

Comment: the thing is if i import urllib.request or if i call urllib.request.urlopen it says the same thing. and what really puzzles me is that i had it running earlier today on these commands that you see above

Comment: He said he's using Python 2.x, not 3.x! They moved `urlopen` into `urllib.request` in Python 3.0 and newer.

Comment: my bad! edited the response to indicate AndiDog's observation. And in addition to his suggestion of checking the file location, you can also invoke `urllib.__dict__.get("urlopen")` to check whether the module actually even contains that operation.

Answer (score 0):

The urlopen function is actually in the urllib2 module.  Try import urllib2 and use urllib2.urlopen

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using Python2 or at least intend to use Python2.
`urlopen` helper function is available in both urllib and urllib2 in Python2.

What you need to do this, execute this script against the correct version of your python

```
C:\Python26\python.exe yourscript.py
```